# Plesk Webserver responds with 304 instead 200

Tags: php, apache, plesk

I have the following simple script:

```
$ts = 1510317885;
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $ts )." GMT" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
echo 'content';
```

I would expect that this script could never answer with a 304 Not modified.
But i have one server which is running Plesk 17.5 which responds with a 304 on every 2+ request. Other servers I manage behave as expected.

I'm trying to find out what's the cause of this. The browser requests the page, apache gets the request, all php code is run, still I see a 304 in the apache log and also in the browser a 304. I assume there might be an Apache module which answers with a 304 when `If-Modified-Since` matches `Last-Modified`, but i could not find such a thing. Or maybe a PHP setting? If I remove the `Last-Modified` Header it works as expected. But I want to keep it.

Can you tell me why the webserver answers here with a 304?